# How is Residual Standard Error (RSE) calculate within R's lm function?

Tags: lm

I performed linear regression in the following way:

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), y1 = c(1.05,2.1,3.5,3.9,4.8,6.1,6.8,7))
mod <- lm(y ~ ., data = df)
summary(mod)
```

And the output is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.49031 -0.22200  0.06267  0.11194  0.61020 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.40917    0.31927  -1.282    0.247    
y1           1.11414    0.06578  16.938 2.71e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3787 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9795,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9761 
F-statistic: 286.9 on 1 and 6 DF,  p-value: 2.708e-06
```

**What formula is used to get "Residual standard error"? How 0.3787 is calculated?**

Any help is welcome.